# Calling ASP.NET Web API from AngularJS throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have an AngularJS web application with ASP.NET Web API as backend (two separate projects). When I'm trying to call Web API service, I'm getting an exception. For example:

Angular:

```
$http.get('api/notes/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.notes = data;
    });
```

Web Api:

```
 public class NoteController : ApiController
{
    private UnitOfWork _unit = new UnitOfWork();

    [Route("api/notes/")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Note> GetAllNotes()
    {
        return _unit.NoteRepository.Get();
    }
/*...*/
}
```

The exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No connection string named 'NoteBookDB' could be found in the application config file.

If I add connection string and entity framework to frontend project, everything run w\o exception, but it creates additional connection to DB, which is obviously wrong. What's my mistake?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular and everything to do with how to configure ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fronend' project and how you adding connection string to it ?

Comment: @mason,thanks, I figured out I've got wrong routing in asp.net.

Comment: @sss, I've got two projects in solution, one of them is client-side (html and javascript) and other back-end(business logic and db). Both have web.config, and I added connection string from back-end to client-side project's web.config file

Comment: @VladimirLevchenko has your client-side project including and mvc controllers or api controllers ?

Comment: @sss
Only one web api controller so far

Comment: @VladimirLevchenko so that is not strictly 'fronend' project as your code in your api controllers is executed on server side. You have to have NoteBookDB in your web.config file otherwise you get exception like in your question.

Comment: @sss, Sorry, I misread the question. Client-side has no controllers, the one I have is in back-end project

Comment: @NoteController basically project contains `NoteController` have to have connection string to NoteBookDB  in web.config

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection string name **"NoteBookDB"** in your database context to the name of the connection string in your web.config file, so you wouldn't need to create a new connection string.